# How to declare a function that only accepts a value of type T if IsSomething<T> is true?

Tags: typescript

I have a complicated generic type `IsInteresting<T>` that becomes either the type `true` or `false` depending on what `T` I give it:

```
type IsInteresting<T> = (/* ... */) ? true : false;
```

Now I want to create a function that receives as first argument an *interesting* value, i.e., a value whose type `U` would cause `IsInteresting<U>` to be `true`. How can I accomplish this?

```
const operateOnInterestingValue: WhatFunctionTypeDoIPutHere = value => {
  // ...
};

let a: T1; // Assume `IsInteresting<T1>` would give `true`
let b: T2; // Assume `IsInteresting<T2>` would give `false`

operateOnInterestingValue(a); // Must compile
operateOnInterestingValue(b); // Must not compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you slightly change `IsInteresting<T>` this way:

```
type IsInteresting<T> = (/* ... */) ? T : never;
```

You can then type your function like this:

```
const operateOnInterestingValue = <T>(value: IsInteresting<T>) => {
  // ...
};
```

The compiler will complain if you try to call `operateOnInterestingValue` with a variable whose `IsInteresting<type>` would resolve to `never`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Thank you very much, this worked!!